# Veritical collapsible menu item using bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4 and i am trying to render simple vertical collapsible menu.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <div id="accordion">
            <div>
                <div id="tags">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTags" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTags">
                        <b>Tags</b>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTags" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="tags" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tag1">Tag 1</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tag2">Tag 2</a></li>                            
                            <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tag3">Tag 3</a></li>                                                        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="tagAttributes">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTagAttributes" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTagAttributes">
                        <b>Attributes</b>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTagAttributes" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="tagAttributes" data-parent="#accordion">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#attribut1">attribut 1</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#attribut2">attribut 2</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#attribut3">attribut 3</a></li>                            
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#attribut4">attribut 4</a></li>                                                        
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="pill" href="#subattribute">Sub Attribute</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sub1">Sub 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#sub2">Sub 2</a></li>                                    
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tag1" role="tabpanel">tag1</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tag2" role="tabpanel">tag2</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tag3" role="tabpanel">tag3</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="attribut1" role="tabpanel">attribut 1</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="attribut2" role="tabpanel">attribut 2</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="attribut3" role="tabpanel">attribut 3</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="attribut4" role="tabpanel">attribut 4</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="subattribute" role="tabpanel">sub attributes</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub1" role="tabpanel">sub 1</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sub2" role="tabpanel">sub 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lax4u/tg98e3hc/3/)

**ISSUE**
The tab pane does not show the second time. For example. Click on Tag 1 it shows corresponding tab pane for tag 1. Then click on Tag 2 it shows corresponding tab pane for tag 2. Now click on Tag 1 again, it does not show corresponding tab pane

If i add `<ul class="nav flex-column"` > ...` then it works. However by doing so removes the bullet points for menu items and sub menu items

How do i make this work with bullet points for each menu item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required `.nav` in order to toggle works. So, you can add another class to undo the nav style that hides the bullets in list.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list flex-column">
  <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tag1">Tag 1</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tag2">Tag 2</a></li>                     
  <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tag3">Tag 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.nav-list {
  padding-left: 40px;
  list-style: disc;
}
```

`padding-left: 40px` and `list-style: disc` are the default values if you didn't have the `.nav` style.

Comment: that worked. But i also have to use `!important` to make it work

Comment: That's weird, when I tested it, didn't need it.